# Can I write this javascript more efficiently with jquery?

Tags: jquery

Do you think jquery could help me get the following script work faster?
Thanks!

```
window.onload=function colorizeCheckedRadios(){                     
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    if (inputs) {
        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i) {
            if(inputs[i].checked&&inputs[i].type=="radio"){
                inputs[i].parentNode.parentNode.style.backgroundColor='#FCE6F4';
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Faster, I don't know. Cleaner and cross browser: yes

```
$(function() {
    $('input:radio:checked').parent().parent().css('background-color', '#FCE6F4');
});
```

Comment: +1 for cleanness and compatibility.  Faster, most likely not --  definitely not in browsers where `querySelectorAll()` is unavailable.

Comment: Thanks for all the quick answers! I implemented the code and to me it seems a bit faster. I'm on Firefox 3.6. Thanks a lot! It is awesome clean code.

Comment: It might actually be a bit faster on browsers that implement `querySelectorAll`, although the speed difference should be negligible anyway.

Comment: each .parent() call is causing a whole new loop through all the inputs found. In case you have alot, then you'd want to write this so you only loop once.

Answer (score 3):

No, because jQuery will parse jQuery selectors used in the code, so it will be slower.

Comment: Speed wise it should make little difference, especially because of how  jQuery is written.

Comment: @Josh K: you're right that it won't make *much* difference but it will be slower.  The question asked if jQuery would make the script faster and more efficient.  The answer to that question is no.

Comment: If you're really worried about the selector there, just don't use a selector: `$(document.getElementsByTagName('input'))...` and it'll work just the same.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this version with jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  $(":radio:checked").parent().parent().css('background-color', '#FCE6F4');
});
```

So, yes, you can slim it down a bit :)

If you knew what the parent you wanted was, say a `<span>`, you can do this:

```
$(function() {
  $(":radio:checked").closest('span').css('background-color', '#FCE6F4');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, probably. jQuery has the jQuery.ready() method which executes the function when the DOM is complete, and not when all the images are loaded. See: http://15daysofjquery.com/quicker/4/

Comment: Why the downvote, please...? An explanation will teach me and the others.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a named ancestor element that can help you exclude most of the rest of the web page starting there will greatly speed up your selector.

```
... tons of html
<div id="radioButtonList">
... the various radio button divs or what nots
</div>
... tons more html

$(function() { 
  $("#radioButtonList :radio:checked").parent().parent().css('background-color', '#FCE6F4'); 
});
```